# how to query associations with a has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with a has_many :through association between User.rb and Practice.rb, with PracticeListing.rb as a join model.

User.rb

```
  has_many :practice_listings
  has_many :practices, through: :practice_listings
```

Practice.rb

```
has_many :practice_listings
has_many :users, through: :practice_listings
```

PracticeListing.rb

```
  belongs_to :practice
  belongs_to :user
```

In one of the controllers, I call this scope method on `user.rb`, passing in the practice_id

```
 scope :lawyers_by_practice, lambda {|practice_id|
  joins(:practices).
  where( users: {practice_id: practice_id},
         users: {lawyer: true},)

  }
```

the query from the logs which shows that practice_id is not being used

```
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "practice_listings" ON "practice_listings"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "practices" ON "practices"."id" = "practice_listings"."practice_id" WHERE "users"."lawyer" = 't' AND (reputation IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY reputation DESC
```

Can you explain how I should have written that scope method to get the desired results?

With the current model set up, I could do `user.practice_ids` for a certain user and get an array of the practice_ids ['2','4']

Update

I tried this way (without joining :practices) in the hopes that the query would select only the users with the relevant practice_id, but it returned every user in the db, even those who didn't have a practice

```
 scope :lawyers_by_practice, lambda {|practice_id|
  where( users: {practice_id: practice_id},
         users: {lawyer: true},)

  }
```

I also tried this way (by joining :practice_listings instead) but it returned entries for every practice_listing, again ignoring the fact that I only wanted use who had a certain practice id

```
scope :lawyers_by_practice, lambda {|practice_id|
    joins(:practice_listings).
  where( users: {practice_id: practice_id},
         users: {lawyer: true},)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` doesn't have a `practice_id`, only `PracticeListing` has.

```
scope :lawyers_by_practice, lambda {|practice_id|
  joins(:practices,:practice_listings).
  where( practice_listings: {practice_id: practice_id},
     users: {lawyer: true},)

  }
```

Comment: I know user doesn't have a practice_id, but I can still do `user.practice_ids`, which is why I got confused. Anyways, your solution seems to only partially work. If a user (say id '55') has two practices (say with practice_ids `[3,12]`, and we're querying for users who have a practice with id '3', user id 55 is still getting returned twice (and therefore listed twice in view).  In other words, because user id 55 has two practice_ids, your query (let's say we're querying practice_id 3) is returning two results for that user. is that clear? is it fixable?

Comment: in Rails 3.2 you can add `.uniq` to the scope making it a `SELECT DISTINCT`. Otherwise it's the expected result, as `join` is a cross product.

Comment: I don't think my comment was clear. Your query (if querying for practice_id 3) is returning two ActiveRecord relation results for user with id 55, even though user with id 55 only has one practice with id 3. I think this might be because user with id 55 also has another practice (with id 12), and it's somehow getting returned from your query even though we're not querying with id 12

Comment: sorry, I commented again before I saw yours. I'm using Rails 4, but anyways, I'll try that .uniq